# Batch single rest requests to batch rest request

Tags: c#, rest

Say I have an api that takes individual get requests and batch requests:
`http://myapiendpoint.com/mysuperitems/1234`

and

`http://myapiendpoint.com/mysuperitems/1234,2345,456,5677`
and in my code I have a method for getting singles:

```
async Task<mysuperitem> GetSingleItem(int x) {
var endpoint = $"http://myapiendpoint.com/mysuperitems/{x}";
//... calls single request endpoint
}
```

but what I want to do is pool the single calls into batch calls.

```
async Task<mysuperitem> GetSingleItem(int x) {
//... pool this request in a queue and retrieve it when batch complete
}
async Task<IEnumerable<mysuperitem> GetMultiItem(IEnumerable<int> ids){
//... gets items and lets single item know it's done
}
```

how would i batch the calls asynchronously and inform the single call of completion. Thinking something with a `ConcurrentQueue` and `Timer` job?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143010/consuming-chunks-from-concurrentqueue

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you can use a System.Timers with Timer.Interval.
And I'd use a normal Dictionary> to make it simple and to easily map id's to tasks, you're most likely batch all requests from that intervall anyway, so no real need for a queue. And then simply sync the GetSingleItem with the GetMultiItem called from the timer like:

```
private Dictionary<int,Task<mysuperitem>> _batchbuffer;
private object _lock = new object();
Task<mysuperitem> GetSingleItem(int id) {
    lock(_lock) {
        return _batchbuffer[id] = new Task<mysuperitem>();
    }
}
async Task GetMultiItem(){
    Dictionary<int,Task<mysuperitem>> temp;
    lock(_lock) {
        temp = new Dictionary<int,Task<mysuperitem>>(_batchbuffer);
        _batchbuffer.Clear()
    }
    var batchResults = // do batch request for temp.Keys;
    foreach(var result in batchResults)
        temp[result.id].complete(result);
}
```

this is ofc batching to reduce server/network load, if you want to increase client performance that's something different.

Comment: is the lock necessary? i'm thinking this could cause some kind of deadlock.

Comment: also, i think this could benefit from a concurrent collection instead of the non concurrent one

Comment: thought so too at first, but the critical section inside GetMultiItem involves two actions. if we'd use a concurrent collection the split of those would introduce a race condition

Comment: and ofc you could still use something different than lock like monitor or something but i usually prefer `keywords` especially for code examples

Answer (score 1):

It seems `Task.WhenAll` is what you need:

```
async Task<mysuperitem> GetSingleItem(int x)
{
    return await ... // calls single request endpoint
}
async Task<IEnumerable<mysuperitem>> GetMultiItem(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    return await Task.WhenAll(ids.Select(id => GetSingleItem(id)));
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, not quite what i'm looking for, i understand the task library and waiting on groups of tasks. what i need to do is pool single calls (without changing my api, so the library callers think they are asking for a single item) into batches

Answer (score 0):

this is a first hack attempt:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using timers = System.Timers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class BatchPoolConsumer<TReturn, TArgs>
    {
        class PoolItem
        {
            private readonly object _itemWriteLock = new object();
            public object ItemWriteLock => _itemWriteLock;
            public Task BlockingTask { get; set; }
            public TReturn ReturnValue { get; set; }
            public Guid BatchId { get; set; }
            public bool IsRead { get; set; }
            public ManualResetEventSlim Slim { get; set; }
        }

        private readonly timers.Timer _batchTimer;
        private readonly timers.Timer _poolCleanerTimer;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TArgs, PoolItem> _taskPool =
            new ConcurrentDictionary<TArgs, PoolItem>();
        private readonly Func<IEnumerable<TArgs>, Task<IEnumerable<(TArgs, TReturn)>>> _batchProcessor;
        private readonly int _consumerMaxBatchConsumption;

        public BatchPoolConsumer(Func<IEnumerable<TArgs>, Task<IEnumerable<(TArgs, TReturn)>>> batchProcessor, TimeSpan interval, int consumerMaxBatchConsumption)
        {
            _batchProcessor = batchProcessor;
            _consumerMaxBatchConsumption = consumerMaxBatchConsumption;
            _batchTimer = InitTimer(interval, BatchTimerElapsed);
            _poolCleanerTimer = InitTimer(interval, PoolCleanerElapesed);
        }

        private static timers.Timer InitTimer(TimeSpan interval, Action<object, timers.ElapsedEventArgs> callback)
        {
            var timer = new timers.Timer(interval.TotalMilliseconds);
            timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => callback(s, e);
            timer.Start();
            return timer;
        }

        private void PoolCleanerElapesed(object sendedr, timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var completedKeys = _taskPool
                .Where(i => i.Value.IsRead)
                .Select(i => i.Key).ToList();
            completedKeys.ForEach(k => _taskPool.TryRemove(k, out _));
        }

        private void BatchTimerElapsed(object sender, timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _batchTimer.Stop();
            var batchId = Guid.NewGuid();
            var keys = _taskPool
                .Where(i => !i.Value.BlockingTask.IsCompleted && !i.Value.IsRead && i.Value.BatchId == Guid.Empty)
                .Take(_consumerMaxBatchConsumption).Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
            keys.ToList()
                .ForEach(k =>
                {
                    if(_taskPool.TryGetValue(k, out PoolItem item))
                    {
                        lock (item.ItemWriteLock)
                        {
                            item.BatchId = batchId;
                        }
                    }
                });
            _batchTimer.Start();
            if (_taskPool
                .Any(pi => pi.Value.BatchId == batchId))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Processing batch {batchId} for {_taskPool.Count(pi => pi.Value.BatchId == batchId)} items");
                var results = _batchProcessor(_taskPool
                    .Where(pi => pi.Value.BatchId == batchId)
                    .Select(i => i.Key)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine($"Completed batch {batchId} for {_taskPool.Count(pi => pi.Value.BatchId == batchId)} items");
                results.ToList().ForEach(r =>
                {
                    if(_taskPool.TryGetValue(r.Item1,out PoolItem val))
                    {
                        lock (val.ItemWriteLock)
                        {
                            val.ReturnValue = r.Item2;
                            val.Slim.Set();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public async Task<TReturn> Get(TArgs args)
        {
            var slim = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                slim.Wait();
            });
            var output = new PoolItem
            {
                BlockingTask = task,
                IsRead = false,
                Slim = slim
            };
            _taskPool[args] = output;
            await task;
            var returnVal = output.ReturnValue;
            output.IsRead = true;
            return returnVal;
        }
    }
}
```